# animate multiple divs expand collapse problem

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to get this circles animated expand collapse to work, you can take a look at it [here](http://www.guarantee-green.com). The problem is once a circle is clicked then the next time you want to expand it the first click is not responding only the second click works. I think a single function that gets id's will solve this but I cant figure how to that.

Here's part of my code:

```
<ul class="circles">
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <p id="circle_info_1_toggle"><a href="#" >Products</a></p>                          
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <p id="circle_info_2_toggle"><a href="#" >Machinery</a></p>                             
    </div>
</li>
```

```
<div id="circles_info_container"> 
    <div id="circle_info_1"> 
        <div class="wrapper">                               
            <h3>We use environmentally-friendly, non-toxic products in all of our work.</h3> 
            <a href="http://www.guarantee-green.com/our-products"><div class="circles_readmore"></div></a> 
        </div> 
    </div>  
    <div id="circle_info_2"> 
        <div class="wrapper">                   
            <h3>We use powerful, modern machinery that removes dirt, grime and soil.</h3> 
            <a href="http://www.guarantee-green.com/our-methods"><div class="circles_readmore"></div></a> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Circle 1*/
$('#circle_info_1_toggle a').click(function() { return false; });   
$('#circle_info_1_toggle a, #circle_info_1').toggle(circle_open_1, circle_close_1);

/* Circle 2*/
$('#circle_info_2_toggle a').click(function() { return false; });   
$('#circle_info_2_toggle a, #circle_info_2').toggle(circle_open_2, circle_close_2);
}); 

// Functions
function close_all_circles() {
    $('#circle_info_1 .wrapper').animate({ height:'0px' }, {duration:250, queue:true});
    $('#circle_info_2 .wrapper').animate({ height:'0px' }, {duration:250, queue:true});
}

    /* Circle 1*/
    function circle_open_1() {  
        close_all_circles();
        $('#circle_info_1 .wrapper').animate({ height:'120px' }, {duration:250});   
    }
    function circle_close_1() {     
            $('#circle_info_1 .wrapper').animate({ height:'0px' }, {duration:250, queue:false});        
    }

    /* Circle 2*/
    function circle_open_2() {  
        close_all_circles();
        $('#circle_info_2 .wrapper').animate({ height:'120px' }, {duration:250});   
    }
    function circle_close_2() {     
            $('#circle_info_2 .wrapper').animate({ height:'0px' }, {duration:250, queue:false});        
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#circles a').click(function () {
    // close all.
    $('#circles_info_container .wrapper').animate({ height:'0px' }, {duration:250, queue:true});

    // open clicked one.
    var num = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('circle_info_', '').replace('_toggle', '');
    $('#circle_info_' + num + ' .wrapper').animate({ height:'120px' }, {duration:250});   
});
```

If you want to make sure the close animations complete before starting to animate the open, you can do that via the `complete` parameter passed to [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), which is a delegate to a callback function that will be invoked once the animation completes.

Comment: Wow that really shortened my code and works great, thanks!
Although I tried to add active class and some padding and it doesn't seem to work correctly maybe you take a look. This are the two lines I've added the open and close
 
// close all.
$('#circle_info_' + num ).animate({ paddingBottom:'0px' });
$('.c' + num ).removeClass('active');

// open clicked one.
  
$('#circle_info_' + num ).animate({ paddingBottom:'20px' }) 
$('.c' + num ).addClass('active');

Comment: And you can't close them now.

Comment: That's a whole separate question/problem and I'm reluctant to do ALL your work for you (might as well hire me for it).  You have enough to start moving in the right direction.  I think you need to read up on JavaScript and jQuery a bit more - go through some tutorials, practice exercises.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which calls hide and show parts with alternate clicks. Your code is working fine and as expected.

---

What i mean is that, if content reletad to circle 1 is already hidden, and if you click it second time, you try to hide corresponding content again. Which does nothing.